# QR Codes Printing, but Not Printing Correctly - Any Ideas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, printing, qr-code

I am mail merging some QR codes via file paths stored in Excel into a label template in MS Word 2013.  I have the whole process with the Ctrl+F9 working properly, but I am stumped on this:

On the 30 label sheet I am trying to print I have 6 labels that are repeating information, and stored in duplicated rows in Excel for this print job. All of the labels have 2 images on them, one is a logo and the other one is a unique QR code for that person. For the first set of 6 labels that print out, everything works perfect.  However, from the 2nd time the information is printed onward all of the merged fields and logo look correct, but the QR codes are printing strangely.  Basically it's the QR code as I want it, but with a copy of itself covering the top left 25% of the QR code.

Print preview doesn't show this happening, only once it's printed does it come out like this.

I've been trying everything I can think of to fix this and don't know what to do.  So far I've: Recreated the document several times, tried duplicating the images in the source folder and giving the links in the Excel document new file paths in case the mail merge feeding from the same .jpg was an issue (even though it's not a problem with the logo)

Any help or insight is greatly appreciate because this is a test run for a larger batch run that I need to get done soon :(  Thank you!

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot of the problematic images?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that the QR Code is a JPG, right?  So what resolution is that set to, as opposed to your printer resolution?  I suspect you could fix this even by updating the printer driver or using a different one, but you haven't included those details to be sure.

Comment: Some thoughts/questions: Which version of Word? What field coding are you using to insert the QR codes? Are you saving your Mail Merge Main Document as a .docx or a .doc (on this kind of thing, .doc is still sometimes a better bet). Assuming you are using a nested INCLUDEPICTURE field, have you tried with/without the \d switch? (And probably irrelevant, but what do the picture paths look like - do they have double-backslash path separators?)

Comment: @SDS, L.B Since a bounty was started on this question are you able to give any further feedback to our questions as this would really help?

Comment: @Adam I started the bounty on this one because it looked like a good question that wasn't receiving enough attention. I personally know almost nothing about QR codes!